# How to close Firefox's current tab?

Tags: c#, firefox, sendkeys

I'm trying closing a current tab in firefox using C#.

I use  `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys("^W")` to firefox and it closes all tab.

However, I can send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to firefox by `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys("^{TAB}")` and the current tab is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending `^w` instead. Notice that the `w` is small and not capital.

When you're sending `W`, you're actually sending <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

The hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> closes all tabs which is the behavior that you see.

So the proper code would be `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys("^w")`